# How to integrate Firebase's Google sign in into Flutter project with different programming environments?

Tags: firebase, flutter

My current project has 2 development environments, dev and production, you can use the keyword "**fluter flavo**r" to find out how to do it. I have found a way to apply Facebook auth in the project but with Google, it is not possible.

This is the order in which the error occurs

1. press the login button
2. choose a google account to login
3. pop-up select account disappear and appear **PlatformException** error in terminal

**Firebase google login**

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show kIsWeb;

Future<User?> signInWithGoogle() async {
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  User? user;

  final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

  final GoogleSignInAccount? googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();

  if (googleSignInAccount != null) {
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
        await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
      idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
    );

    try {
      final UserCredential userCredential =
          await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
      user = userCredential.user;
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'account-exists-with-different-credential') {
        print("account-exists-with-different-credential");
// handle the error here
      } else if (e.code == 'invalid-credential') {
        print("invalid-credential");
// handle the error here
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("another erro ${e}");
// handle the error here
    }
  }

  return user;
}
```

**main.dart for dev flavor**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:com.bnk.myvincom/ui/my_app.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

import 'config/app_config.dart';
import 'constants/strings.dart';
import 'di/components/service_locator.dart';
// import 'firebase_a'
import 'package:firebase_crashlytics/firebase_crashlytics.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await setPreferredOrientations();
  await setupLocator();

  // Initialize Firebase.
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  // dev config
  AppConfig devAppConfig = AppConfig(appName: Strings.appNameDev, flavor: 'dev');

  // This line code just to test if crash server work, it make app crash
  // FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.crash();

  return runZonedGuarded(() async {
    // WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    runApp(MyApp(devAppConfig));
  }, (error, stack) {
    print(stack);
    print(error);
  });
}

Future<void> setPreferredOrientations() {
  return SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
  ]);
}
```

**login page**

```
import 'package:com.bnk.myvincom/services/firebase_facebook_login_service.dart';
import 'package:com.bnk.myvincom/services/firebass_google_login_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
// import 'package:flutter_';

class FacebookLogin extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FacebookLoginState createState() => _FacebookLoginState();
}

class _FacebookLoginState extends State<FacebookLogin> {
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  bool _isLoggedIn = false;
  String? _message;

  Future _loginWithFacebook() async {
    // TODO: handle login
    try {
      await signInWithFacebook().then((value) => {
            print("Facebook  ${value}"),
            setState(() {
              _message = "Logged in as ${value.user!.displayName}";
              _isLoggedIn = true;
            })
          });
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      print('Facebook failed with error code: ${e.code}');
      print(e.message);
    }
  }

  Future _loginWithGoogle() async {
    // TODO: handle login
    try {
      await signInWithGoogle().then((value) => print("Google về ${value}"));
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      print('Google failed with error code: ${e.code}');
      print(e.message);
    }
  }

  Future _logout() async {
    // TODO: Handle logout
    // SignOut khỏi Firebase Auth
    await _auth.signOut();
    // Logout facebook
    // await _facebooklogin.logOut();
    setState(() {
      _isLoggedIn = false;
    });
  }

  Future _checkLogin() async {
    // TODO: check if user logged in
    // Kiểm tra xem user đã đăng nhập hay chưa
    final user = await _auth.currentUser;
    if (user != null) {
      setState(() {
        _message = "Logged in as ${user.displayName}";
        _isLoggedIn = true;
      });
    }
  }

  _buildFacebookLogin() {
    return Center(
      child: _isLoggedIn
          ? Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(_message!),
                SizedBox(height: 12.0),
                OutlineButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    _logout();
                  },
                  child: Text('Logout'),
                ),
              ],
            )
          : RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _loginWithFacebook();
              },
              color: Colors.blue,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              child: Text('Login with Facebook'),
            ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _checkLogin();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        _buildFacebookLogin(),
        SizedBox(height: 30),
        _buildGoogleLogin(),
      ],
    ));
  }

  _buildGoogleLogin() {
    return Center(
      child: _isLoggedIn
          ? Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(_message!),
                SizedBox(height: 12.0),
                OutlineButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    _logout();
                  },
                  child: Text('Logout'),
                ),
              ],
            )
          : RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _loginWithGoogle();
              },
              // color: Colors.blue,
              textColor: Colors.red,
              child: Text('Login with Google'),
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Error log**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you tried everything like creating a new debug.toolkey, adding SHA1 and SHA-256 and it still doesn't work, you're not the only one.

The reason the above ways don't work is that their project is not either a personal project or is not split into **multiple development environments**. As I mentioned my project has 2 environments **dev** and **prod**. This is something that makes your brain explode, by default **google-service.json** only corresponds to the **package** you registered for firebase. That is, you use the package "com.iosBK.todoapp" to register, but in the google-service.json file on your computer, it is named "com.iosBK.todoapp.**dev**" or "com.iosBK.todoapp.**prod**" (how many development environments you have, the more google-service.json files you have).

If it's too hard to understand, think of it as simple as this. On the local machine you have 2 environments, **dev** and **prod**, there will be 2 packages **com.iosBK.todoapp.dev** and **com.iosBK.todoapp.prod** corresponding to **dev** and **prod** development environments. But on the firebase side, there will only be one package, **com.iosBK.todoapp**, as registered before. So when you run the app, Firebase doesn't recognize your package, causing an **PlatformException** error.

Do this to fix this error

1. Go to website Google Cloud console
2. Select the project with the same name as the project you created on Firebase
3. Look in the picture below
   [image]
4. Click on the red shaded area as shown
   [image]

5. You will see that the default package does not have .dev or .prod

6. Click "**Create Credentials**", choose "**Oath client ID**", choose **Application type** as **android**, and **copy** everything in the place you opened it just now and change **only one place** which is the **package name** (you can change the name but it doesn't matter). I will use a dummy package name to make it easier to understand, my default package is "**com.ioteks.todoapp**", I will copy that name and paste it in the new Oath key and add .dev like this "**com.ioteks.todoapp.dev**"
7. Just finished for the dev environment, for the prod environment you do the same but change the word **dev** to **prod**
8. Repeat the Oath key generation the same number of times as the environment you created. I only have 2 environments so I only generate 2 keys, if you have 3, or 5, feel free to create
9. Make sure you add enough SHA1 and SHA-256 to your project when doing those step
10. That is.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try if it helps

- Uninstall App
- Flutter Clean
- Add Debug Sha1 in firebase console if it's not there
- Download and google-service.json
- Run app on device

Comment: Sorry bro, it not working